# Extracting text from several images

Tags: cycle, text-extraction

I want to extract text from several images.
I want to do it in colab.
I know how to do it with one image:https://github.com/bhadreshpsavani/ExploringOCR/blob/master/OCRusingTesseract.ipynb
But how to do it in a cycle, because I have more than a hundred pictures?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there any concept of a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my images in colab.research in root directory and resolved this task with following code:

```
image_ext = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']
directory = '/'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
  ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
  if ext not in image_ext:
    continue
  filename = os.path.join(directory, file)
  
  extracted_information = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
  print(extracted_information)
```